# Create counter without database with JavaScript to increase one every two seconds even if u refresh

Tags: javascript

I have created the counter by js and it works well but increase only after refreshing
[Working js-demo](https://js-demo.com/index.php?ref=479af9b14648)

```
var initialDate = new Date(2020, 12, 28);
var now = Date.now();
var difference = now - initialDate;
var millisecondsPerDay = .001 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
var daysSince = Math.floor(difference / millisecondsPerDay +20);
// Write result to HTML
document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = daysSince;
```

I need it to show the increase without refresh make it dynamic

Answer (score 2):

Wrap it in a function and call it periodically with `setInterval()`

```js
function updateHtml() {
  var initialDate = new Date(2020, 12, 28);
  var now = Date.now();
  var difference = now - initialDate;
  var millisecondsPerDay = .001 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
  var daysSince = Math.floor(difference / millisecondsPerDay + 20);
  // Write result to HTML
  document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = daysSince;
}
// for initial load, execute the function immediately
updateHtml();
// then schedule the function to be executed every 2000 milliseconds
setInterval(updateHtml, 2000);
```

```html
<div id="counter"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks it works now https://js-demo.com/index.php?ref=7599769d01d5

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `setTimeout` function to have your code repeat itself, which will update your counter element.

`setTimeout` accepts a delegate function, which will be executed once the timer has elapsed. Once this happens, we can setup another timer to repeat the same function over and over again.

```
var initialDate = new Date(2020, 12, 28);
var millisecondsPerDay = .001 * 60 * 60 * 1000;

function updateCounter() {
  var now = Date.now();
  var difference = now - initialDate;
  var daysSince = Math.floor(difference / millisecondsPerDay +20);
  // Write result to HTML
  document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = daysSince;
  
  setTimeout(updateCounter, 1000);
}

updateCounter();
```

The above snippet of code creates a 'recursive' function, that is executed once every second.